# App is taking long time to open after restart the android device

Tags: marketing-cloud, geolocation, mobilepush

Recently we have added the Geofence feature in to our app. After adding this feature, we have noticed the app is not responding for long time after restart the phone. This was only happening on Android.

I have realized this will not happen, if we remove the following code from Android manifest file.

```
<!-- This receiver will reset the Google Device Token when the package is replaced. -->
        <receiver android:name="com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPackageReplacedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
                <category android:name="com.gowireless.mobile" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But removing above code from manifest has effected to the Geofence feature.

Could You Please Advice.

Comment: The PACKAGE_REPLACED receiver will only be triggered when the application is updated.  What version of the SDK are you using?  In what way did removing that receiver affect Geofences?

Comment: It appears as if you're running v3.5.x but knowing exactly which version will still be helpful.  Also, if this receiver is being fired it will be evident in the log.  Please provide the LogCat output leading up to and through the delay.

Comment: Any update on this?  Can you provide answers to my questions in the comments above?

Comment: Hi Bill, Sorry, I was away from the office last few days. 

Yes, I am running 3.5.0, The issue is coming if the app open after restarted the device. Since I cant Edit, or write full error log on here, I opend a new question.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106429/app-error-after-restarting-the-device

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/107533/16482 has worked around the issue for versions prior to 4.0 of our SDK.  Version 4.0 has been out for a year.  Please consider upgrading.