# App error After restarting the device

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, geolocation, mobilepush-android, push

I am using Et SDK 3.5.0, After I enabled the Geofence feature on the app, it will generate an error after restarting the device and opening the app.

```
E/ERROR>>>﹕ Initialization did not complete in a timely fashion.
com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETException: Initialization did not complete in a timely fashion.
        at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush.initiateLatch(ETPush.java:160)
        at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush.pushManager(ETPush.java:138)
        at com.gowireless.mobile.MenuActivity.ETPushEnabler(MenuActivity.java:57)
        at com.gowireless.mobile.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The issue is generating from ETPushEnabler();

Comment: Can you please provide your readyAimFire call and from which class are you making this call?

Comment: I am calling this method in oncreate() method in MainApplication Class.

Comment: ETPush.readyAimFire(getApplicationContext(),
                            CONSTS_API.getEtAppId(),
                            CONSTS_API.getAccessToken(),
                            CONSTS_API.getGcmSenderId(),
                            true,     // enable ET Analytics
                            true,     // enable Location Manager, if you purchased this feature
                            false);    // enable Cloud Page, if you purchased this feature

Comment: Please open a support case through your account manager so we can setup a meeting to discuss and/or update your question with your readyAimFire() call as well as any subsequent work you're doing with ETPush (setting attributes, tags, etc.)  Please don't add that data as a comment.  Update your question above.

Comment: Hi Bill, Thank you very much for your response. And would like to say the issue has resolved. I will post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has resolved by adding ET registration as a background service. And I am calling till getting the internet connection.

The issue was, after restart the device, it will take some time to take the connection, So in initial moment the app is trying to register in ET without connection.

If we are adding a background service for that, the UI will load and, ET register after a trusted internet connection has established in the device.

Comment: This is no longer required in versions 4.0+ of the SDK.